# Allow service-level-access only from IstioGateway/Virtual Service

Tags: istio

We have an api service which should be accessible only by a particular Istio gateway/virtual service.

Can this be achieved by istio's `AuthorizationPolicy`?

```
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: deny-all
  namespace: selfserviceportal
spec:
  {}
---
apiVersion: security.istio.io/v1beta1
kind: AuthorizationPolicy
metadata:
  name: api-server-svc
  namespace: selfserviceportal
spec:
  rules:
  - from:
    - source:
        # How do I reference the istio gateway/virtual service here?
    to:
    - operation:
        methods:
        - GET
selector:
    matchLabels:
    app: api-server-svc
```

This is the gateway which should be allowed:

```
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: Gateway
metadata:
  name: api-server-gateway
spec:
  selector:
    istio: ingressgateway # use Istio default gateway implementation
  servers:
  - port:
      number: 80
      name: http
      protocol: HTTP
    hosts:
    - "ssp-api-server.internalroot.net"
---
apiVersion: networking.istio.io/v1alpha3
kind: VirtualService
metadata:
  name: api-server-vservice
spec:
  hosts:
  - "ssp-api-server.internalroot.net"
  gateways:
  - api-server-gateway
  http:
  - match:
    - uri:
        prefix: /api
    route:
    - destination:
        port:
          number: 8000
        host: api-server-svc
```

Comment: Hi, from what I know You can't specify `Gateway` in `AuthorizationPolicy` as a 
 `source`. However what You want can be achieved in other ways. I will post an answer once I verify it.

Comment: After verifying it is not a good idea to filter access to services by which gateway traffic is coming from. A `VirtualService` can then be bound to a gateway to control the forwarding of traffic arriving at a particular host or gateway port. More info: https://istio.io/docs/reference/config/networking/gateway/